# Why my Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) base receives several request(write) per second, when my app does nothing?

Tags: mysql, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, permanent

My app is inactive, waiting for a http request.
Nevertheless, the MySQL database received a **permanent 15 requests(writes)** per second, day and night.
Then, I have stopped replication, and binary logging.
Now, the graph shows about **6 requests(writes) per second**, with a peak to 10 req/sec every 5 mn.
Can you help me to stop that costly load?
[graph showing permanent load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrCUs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Over at the documentation for Cloud SQL metrics, you can find the following:

The Number of Writes metric is the number of write operations to disk. Write activity is generated even if your application is not active, because Cloud SQL instances write to a system table approximately every second (except for replicas).

This is most likely what you are seeing in the metrics of your instance. You can read more over at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-info#available_metrics

Comment: I understand, thanks. My previous sql database on Google App Engine had not such periodic writes: cheaper.